# git remote -v не показывает список репозиториев

Tags: git

GitBush: git remote -v

не показывает список удаленных репо. В чем дело? У меня в аккаунте их 2 штуки.

```
$ git remote
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Информация [отсюда](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: В ошибке же все написано. Если не знаете английский, то хотя бы используйте переводчик, а ответ вам уже написали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git Вам как бы намекает, что в папке, в который вызывается команда нету папки .git. А вернее, папка (каталог), где Вы вызываете команду, не является git-репозиторием.

Для начала, перепроверьте, там ли вызывается команда.

Если с этим все в порядке вызовите `git-init` в вызывающей папке. И добавьте remote.

Comment: если правильно понял, в локальной папке Git, где содержатся все локальные версии удаленных репо, её нужно проинициализировать git init ?

Comment: @Proshka, я не совсем понял этот Ваш вопрос. Но думаю, раз Вы уже вызываете `git remote`, то `git init` уже была выполнена. А вообще, я бы советовал Вам пользоваться встроенными scm в Вашей IDE (в любой уважающей себя IDE это реализовано).

Comment: разобрался, спасибо. @Ep1demic - спасибо за помощь и совет - воспользуюсь. Директория с локальными версиями была не проинициализирована. После git init и далее git remote add для каждого проекта, естественно, после git remove -v высыпался весь список добавленных проектов. Спасибо всем. @ korytoff - с английским у меня в порядке. Вопрос в нехватке времени и в спешке.

Comment: команда: git remote -v #может не выдавать вообще ответа или писать что это ошибка. В каких случах это происходит. 1.Локальный репозиторий не инициализирован. 2. Вам нужно подключить ветку удаленного репозитория: git remote add origin https://github.com/имя_ник_пользователя/ИмяРепозитория.git

Вы можете посмотреть мою публикацию на habr, если будет интересно: https://habr.com/ru/post/451662/